# group by but counting just active rows-SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
scenes
------
scene_id
title
video_url
modified_at
uuid


likes
----
scene_id
uuid
active


users
-----
uuid
username
```

Problem 1:
I want to get the number of likes for scenes,scene_id, author in descending order; please note that we need to count just those likes which are active in likes table!

My try:

```
SELECT s.scene_id,s.video_url,s.title,s.uuid, u.username as author,s.data,count(l.active) as likes

 FROM scenes s
    left join likes l
        on l.scene_id = s.scene_id
    join users u
        on u.uuid = s.uuid
  where s.video_url  IS not NULL
  group by s.scene_id
  order by modified_at DESC;
```

But this is counting all of the likes, irrespective whether it is active or not! I dont know how I can add that one in my query!

Problem 2:

Also I wonder whether it is possible to add another column in the result set which shows a specific user (the uuid can be passed and used in where clause) has liked each scene in the result set or not? Is it possible to have this result in just one query?

Please let me know if you need more clarification!

Thanks!

Comment: ?????  SUM ?????? - or ELSE NULL

Comment: umm; Nice man! now I tried sum(l.active) and it is working! but if it not liked it returnes null, so I tried ISNULL(sum(l.active)) and gives me error! any idea? Also do you have any idea about problem 2 as well?

Comment: Also tried SUM(ISNULL(l.active, 0)) and it says: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: what are the possible values of 'active' column, i.e., how do you specify the active like?

Comment: There are a few options. Here's one: COALESCE(SUM(x=y),0)

Comment: Thanks to your help, problem 1 is solved by using SUM(IFNULL(l.active, 0)) ; do you have any idea about problem 2?

Comment: active is just 1 or 0

Comment: Do you have any ideas about problem 2?

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the predicate on the `active` column is straightforward; it just depends on how that's represented... is that an integer type column, using 0 and/or NULL to indicate that it's "inactive", and a 1 and/or any positive integer to indicate that it's `active`?

To get "number of likes for scenes,scene_id, author in descending order", you could do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(l.scene_id) AS cnt_likes
     , s.scene_id        AS scene_id
     , a.username        AS author
  FROM scenes s
  LEFT
  JOIN users a
    ON a.uuid = s.uuid
  LEFT
  JOIN likes l 
    ON l.scene_id = s.scene_id 
   AND l.active+0
 GROUP BY s.scene_id
 ORDER BY cnt_likes DESC, s.scene_id DESC, a.username DESC
```

If the column `active` is character type, and you are using a value of "yes" to indicate a like is active, you'd need to change the predicate,

Replace:

```
   AND l.active+0
```

With:

```
   AND l.active = 'yes'
```

etc.

---

For the second question, identifying the users that have 'active likes' for a scene

(i.e. rows included in the aggregate), that's problematic, because there can be multiple users with a like for a scene... which of those users do we identify to return, just any one of them, all of them?...   i just re-read your question more carefully.  You want to know if one particular identified user has a `like` for the scene.

Just test if the uuid on the like row is equal to the value you are looking for, and return a 0 or 1, and then get the MAX() of that.

e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(l.scene_id)         AS cnt_likes
     , s.scene_id                AS scene_id
     , a.username                AS author
     , MAX(l.uuid = 'auser')     AS liked_by_user
  FROM scenes s
  LEFT
  JOIN users a
    ON a.uuid = s.uuid
  LEFT
  JOIN likes l
    ON l.scene_id = s.scene_id 
   AND l.active+0
 GROUP BY s.scene_id
 ORDER BY cnt_likes DESC, s.scene_id DESC, a.username DESC
```

**FOLLOWUP**

The expression

```
     MAX(l.uuid = 11 )
```

can return 1, 0 or NULL.  (1 would be equivalent to boolean TRUE, 0 to boolean false, and a NULL would be unknown, or in this case, we'd treat it as also being FALSE.

In MySQL, integers can be treated as booleans, and booleans are handled as integers.

To return strings 'true' or 'false', you could use an IF() function

```
     IF(MAX(l.uuid = 11 ), 'true', 'false')
```

Comment: Nice man! For the second problem! I'm getting a uuid in the backend and when I list the scenes, in the last column I just need to say whether the user (uuid) that I get as an input imagine uuid=10 liked which senes in your output result

Comment: @user3399784: you did explain it well, you actually explained it in your original question, I just missed it.  I've updated my answer, to show one way to do it. (Obviously, there's more than one solution, I've just shown one way to do it.) (If `active` is integer type, you can omit the "+0" on the predicate; we'd want that if it active was character type, '0', '1')

Comment: Man you are awesome! I realy appreciate your help!

Comment: Your solution deserves +100 likes

Comment: @user3399784: also, if you don't care about any "zero" counts, you can use  `[INNER] JOIN` operations, rather than `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`. I'm glad you found my answer helpful. I'm not sure why your question received a downvote, seemed like a good question to me.)

Comment: Just is it possible if for the 'liked_by_user' return 0 or preferably false and if they liked 'true'; now in the results we have nulls and 0,1; can we cnahge all of them to true, false and get rid of nulls?...

Comment: IFNULL(MAX(l.uuid = 11),0) returns 0,1 and got rid of nulls; is there any way to change them to True and False?

Comment: @user3399784: in MySQL, boolean expressions return integers (NULL for unknown, 0 for FALSE, 1 for TRUE). And integers can be treated as booleans, too: NULL is NULL, 0 is FALSE, other values are TRUE. If you want to return string values 'true'/'false'...   you could use the `IF()` function: **`IF(MAX(l.uuid = 11),'true','false')`**